# Access V channel only in HSV system

Tags: opencv

I want to display V channel image only, so I wrote this, why I failed when trying this?
I can compile it but I cannot execute it when I imshow("V",V);

```
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> 
  using namespace cv;
    int main(){
    Mat image;
    Mat V;
   namedWindow( "Gray image", 2 );
     while(1){
 image = imread( "d://Gaa6P.png", 1 );
        for (int r=0; r< image.rows; r++ ){
         for( int c =0;c< image.cols; c++){
            Vec3b intensity= image.at<Vec3b>(r, c);
            uchar v=intensity.val[2];
            V.at<uchar>(r,c)=v;
             }
          }
      imshow( "Gray image", image );
      imshow("V",V);
      waitKey(0);
           }
     return 0; }
```

Thanks all, it works now.

```
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> 
 using namespace cv;
 int main(){
 Mat image;
 Mat V;
 namedWindow( "Gray image", 2 );
while(1){
image = imread( "d://Gaa6P.png", 1 );
cvtColor(image,image,CV_RGB2HSV);
V.create(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC1);
    for (int r=0; r< image.rows; r++ ){
     for( int c =0;c< image.cols; c++){
        Vec3b intensity= image.at<Vec3b>(r, c);
        uchar v=intensity.val[0];
        V.at<uchar>(r,c)=v;
         }
      }
  imshow( "Gray image", image );
  imshow("V",V);
  waitKey(0);
       }
  return 0; }
```

Comment: V.at<float> sounds like a bad idea, since hsv is 3 uchar channels. make it : Mat V(h,w,CV_8U);   V.at<uchar>(r,c)= intensity[2];

Comment: or like this : Mat chan[3]; split(HSV,chan); // use chan[2];

Comment: @berak: `V.at<uchar>(r,c)= intensity[2];` is the wrong method. It should be `V.at<uchar>(r,c)= intensity.val[2]; `

Comment: @skm, Vec3b (ouch i missed that above) has a [] operator. you're probably talking about Scalar, which has val[i] as well as a [] operator

Comment: @berak,Thank you, I know I can get the V channel by use split(HSV,channel), but I cannot figure out why I can not get the image by this method.  I reedit the codes,but it still failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot get the value in `V-channel` directly by writing `float v=intensity[2];` because `intensity` is of `Vec3f` type.

So, if you want to access intensity value in `V-channel` use the following:

```
float v=intensity.val[2];
```

That was the problem in your code.

**Secondly**, i would suggest you to use `<uchar>` i.e.

`Vec3b intensity= HSV.at<Vec3b>(r, c);`

and **then do the typecast** to convert the value into float i.e.

`float v= (float) intensity.val[2];`

Comment: Thank you, I try to use uchar v=intensity.val[2]; but it seems that I still cannot get image. I know I can use split function to get image but I just donot know why I cannot get image.  I add all codes here.:)

Comment: @Diame: your code seems fine but just use `V.create(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC1);` after declaring `Mat V;`

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning values into image V whose memory is not initialized yet. After performing imread you should write:

```
V.create(image.size(), CV_8U);
```

Also are you sure that png image you are reading is in HSV format and not RGB?

Comment: Thanks for your reminding,I add cvtColor(image,image,CV_RGB2HSV); now.